# How to switch temperature values to Fahrenheit in OpenWeatherMap

Tags: openlayers, weather-api, openweathermap

I'm using openweathermap service to show map with the curent weather. Temperature displays in Celsius. But I need to switch it to Fahrenheit. And I can't find any parameter to do it.

Can anybody help me to handle with this issue?

Looking forward to your reply.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution. The problem was that I used OWM.OpenLayers.1.3.4.js instead of OWM.OpenLayers.1.3.6.js. And to display temperature in Fahrenheit I had to use 'units' parameter.

```
var weather = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.OWMWeather("Current weather", {units : 'imperial'}); // imperial - Fahrenheit, metric - Celsius
```

Hope it will be helpful.

Thanks.